# Как отключить показ загрузки статических файлов в Miniprofiler для asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2, profiler

Я использую Miniprofiler в asp.net core2.0 приложении. Настройка в Startup.cs

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options => {
            options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";
            (options.Storage as MemoryCacheStorage).CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter();
            options.ResultsAuthorize = request => !Program.DisableProfilingResults;
        });
```

Для каждого подключения я делаю следующее:

```
DbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            return new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
```

Примеры взяты отсюда https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileSql.
При выводе информации, я вижу загрузку статического контента(js, css и прочее) вместе с запросами к БД, как мне от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо app.UseMiniProfiler(); вызывать после app.UseStaticFiles(); в Startup.cs. Ответ дали тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776999/how-to-disable-the-display-of-loading-static-files-in-miniprofiler-for-asp-net-c